# What is the result of a reduction operation called?

Tags: terminology, reductions

Is there a commonly used term for *the result of a reduction operation*?

"reductant" does not quite sound right...

Answer (score 2):

In the context of reducing one language to another, I have only ever seen this referred to using phrases such as "the problem being reduced to", "the target of the reduction", etc. I don't think there is a single word for it—certainly not one that would be universally understood.